# Error in sending raw sockets in python on windows

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to create raw socket in python on OS : windows.
It doesn't work and I saw it might be due to premissions.
Anyone know how can I check if I have premissions or how to get them?
Thank you!

This is the error message after writing 3 lines:

```
import socket
import sys
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_RAW)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to be a member of the Administrators group.

See [TCP/IP Raw Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the MSDN:

> Raw sockets offer the capability to manipulate the underlying transport, so they can be used for malicious purposes that pose a security threat. Therefore, only members of the Administrators group can create sockets of type `SOCK_RAW` on Windows 2000 and later.

and

> **Note**  To use a socket of type `SOCK_RAW` requires administrative privileges. Users running Winsock applications that use raw sockets must be a member of the Administrators group on the local computer, otherwise raw socket calls will fail with an error code of `WSAEACCES`. On Windows Vista and later, access for raw sockets is enforced at socket creation. In earlier versions of Windows, access for raw sockets is enforced during other socket operations.

Comment: so how can i get these remissions?

Comment: You need to have Administrator privileges by being in the Administrators group.

Comment: @user3371183: You need your account added to the Administrators group. Talk to your sysadmin. If you're doing this yourself, google "add account to administrators group".